swiper mousewheel vertical fires when not fully in the view
I have section before swiper and section after swiper. I want the swiper 1st (or last) slide to be fully in view before the swiper fires. I tried using scroll event but was not reliable enough. I did not find in the documentation a parameter that would reliably work. Any idea?
Detailed
When a user slides over the Swiper then it triggers the swiper so it swipes the slides. However the 1st slide (or the last slide if sliding from bottom) does not need to be 100% in the view for the swiper to trigger swiping slides. That leads to poor user experience when a slide 1 (or slide 4) if 50% in the view but the mouse is on the swiper that changes the slides.
My idea how to fix it is when scrolling from top (from const starterElement) into const swiperElement and when the top of const swiperElement is 30% above the fold I want to trigger an event that will move the const swiperElement top to the top of the screen (eg. slide 1 full into view since slide 1 is 100vh).
The same happens with the last slide. When user slides from bottom to top over const sectionAfterSwiper and const swiperElement enters 30% from the top to the view I want to use an event that will scroll the bottom of const swiperElement into the bottom of the view (slide 4 full into view since slide 4 is 100vh)
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/little-silence-vtwx4y?layout=%257B%2
I tried several ways using JS event, using CSS, sticky sections. Nothing worked
